# Issues installing new SSD in laptop

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd, ubuntu-14.04, asus-laptop

I have recently purchased a Cruciall M400 SSD for my Asus V551LB-DB71T laptop.  I built a recovery drive using Asus backtracker on the original HDD installed on my laptop (the model # is: ST1000LM024). When I put the new SSD into the laptop and inserted a Windows 8 installer disk and booted from it, it was unable to see that there was a drive installed, and thus I could not install to the SSD. The Bios detects the SSD as being present in the computer.

I then put the recovery drive into the computer and loaded up the command prompt tools and ran diskpart to detect disks, it saw the disk and I was able to perform commands on it. I then went back in with the Windows 8 installer and tried using diskpart, it could not see it.

Next, I tried using the ubuntu installer to install, but once again, it could not detect the new SSD. I then went back to the old HDD with both the Windows 8 and Ubuntu installers, both could see the HDD. I then installed a different HDD into the laptop, and once again, both installers could see it. Finally, I put a seperate SSD into the laptop, and once again, the installers were unable to install to the other SSD as well.

I have tried messing around with many BIOS settings, but nothing seems to work. The SATA controller is on AHCI, Fast boot and secure boot are both disabled.

It seems like SSDs just don't seem to work in this laptop, my other computer doesn't have a problem with any of these HDDs or SSDs, so theres not a problem with the drives themselves. I've also ensured the firmware is up to date.

I've been working on this for quite a while and figured I'd ask here for help. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

It could simply be this: the installers (windows 8 and ubuntu) do not contain the driver for your SSD.

There are many free Windows Preinstallation Environment (Win PE) that supports many SSD drives. You need to boot from those PE that can see your SSD.

Alternatively, you could also download you SSD driver, usually from the manufacture. When you are booted to the step that asks you where to install the system, there is an option says "load driver" (or something similar, I don't have an English version of the system disk, sorry). Once the SSD driver is loaded, you should be able to see the SSD drive.

AND (very important)

install the system with the SSD driver. This is, to include the SSD driver to your system while installing. If you loaded the driver using the windows 7 (7or8) installation disk, that is automatically done.

Or try to integrate the driver using customization tools like 7lite. (or WinNTSetup, which is a system image deployment tool)

If you dont integrate the driver, you can finish the installation process, but you will fail to boot the system.

I have helped several friends install windows 7 (and 8) onto their new SSDs.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Might help to explain how to do all you describe

Comment: I will try my best. I assumed it was CLEAR enough (in words) though.

Comment: I could answer better with a picture showing how to do that. But sorry I am new and don't have sufficient reputation to upload one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried using WinPE, though I was unable to understand how to use it to install to the SSD. I was also unable to find any drivers appropriate for my SSD, only firmware. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Joseph, again, i dont have sufficient reputation to post any picture, so I cant really show you. But if you refer to http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/149612-winntsetup-v361/ on how to install using WinNT setup. It's basically a system image deployment tool.

I "think" the MAIN issue is, you dont have a driver for the SSD. If you can't see the SSD from your current WinPE, then you can't install it.

Comment: Here is an alternative solution if you really can't find the SSD driver. 

When you load your old HDD, you can see the new SSD. So partition it to a primary partition, set as "active". Use WinNT setup, to deploy the system image (install it). 

DONT reboot it right away. Take off your HDD, try boot with only the SSD. If may be working.

Comment: Also, you could try it with IDE (instead of AHCI). If it works, you can update the driver later and change back to AHCI.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I loaded up WinPE and ran the diskpart tools, and they were in fact able to see the drive and work with it. How can I use this to help me install windows 8? Also, in the bios. only AHCI is available.

Comment: Sorry this wasnt clear enough. Only if I can upload pictures, that will be great. But bear with me, if you download the WinNT setup from the link I gave you above, input your win8 disk, start winnt setup, choose the image file, usually in your disk drive:\sources\install.esd -- this is THE file. Then choose your system partition, C:\ for destination, click setup. Wait and reboot! Hopefully you can go into your system without any problem (it should！)